# `macOS light` theme has a dark editor background in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

As can be seen here the `theme` is set to `macOS Light` .. but the editor background is dark.  Is that expected?

[image]

Instead when selecting `Intellij light` we do have a white background.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh this is interesting. After having changed to the `Intellij light` if I now select the `macOS light` again it does show up as white:

[image]

So the answer is:

> choose some other theme then just come on back to where you started